# URI of an image stored in SQLite database

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Images are stored in my SQLite database, I need to attach image on user's choice to email/mms application. But such application accepts image only via URI format (`Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`), not directly the byte array/image itself.

So now I need a URI of image stored in SQLite db. How can I retrieve it?
Or do I need to write my custom content-provider for it?

Comment: Isn't a URI just a string?  Store it in another field in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to write your own content provider, as you mentioned - without one, the OS has no way to associate your database with a URI

Answer (score 0):

This code for me. you can get proper solution

```
 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
         ImageView imageView=(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {


            bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
             .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

            byte[] bytarray = Base64.decode(encodedImageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bmimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytarray, 0,
                    bytarray.length);

            myDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO imgtbl VALUES('"+encodedImageString+"');");
            Cursor c= myDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM imgtbl", null);

           c.moveToFirst();
           String img=c.getString(0);
           byte[] byarray = Base64.decode(img, Base64.DEFAULT);
           Bitmap bmimg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byarray, 0,
                   byarray.length);

            ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
            ImageView iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img3);

            iv.setImageBitmap(bmimg);
            iv1.setImageBitmap(bmimg);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```